# Unable to locate ListOrderedMap?

Tags: java, classpath, apache-commons-collection

I have included all the 6 jars (beanutils, lang, logging, collections, ezmorph, json-lib). Its working fine in simple struts application. But in my struts application, although I have included all jar files, its shows a `NoClassDefFoundError` about `ListOrderedMap`.

I don't know how to make my app know that class. But I have included like other required jars for different functionality.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: That class is part of Apache Commons Collections. Check if you have the right version (3.0 or newer) of the Apache Commons Collections jar file in your classpath - if it's a web app, it should be in `WEB-INF/lib` of your war file.

Comment: @Jesper - that can be an answer as well.

Comment: The specified jar is in WEB-INF/lib folder. Its is working perfectly in other apps. I dont know the problem.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you ever manager to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Class [`ListOrderedMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap.html) is part of [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) (since version 3.0).

To be able to use it, you must have the JAR file that contains it on the classpath. The JAR file is most likely named `commons-collections-3.2.1.jar` (or something similar).

If you are creating a web application packaged in a WAR file, then you should put the library in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder inside the WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even tho there is NOW a newer v4.x for commons-collections, the 4.x do NOT work!

So, get the older highest version from v3.x, namely: v3.2.1

If you're using maven, like I am, here's my complete working dependencies list:

```
  <dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
<artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<!-- <classifier>jdk15</classifier> -->
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
<groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
<groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
<groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
<version>1.9.1</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
<groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.1.3</version>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
<artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
<version>1.0.6</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
<groupId>xom</groupId>
<artifactId>xom</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
   </dependency>
```